# Launch activity when device is locked android 8+

Tags: android, android-activity, lockscreen

I have a very simple application in android in the first page there is a button and when you click on it after then seconds it will open another activity but I want to show the second activity when the device is locked in android 8,9  and 10
what is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you should be able to add a `BroadcastReceiver` to monitor when the screen is off `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` is triggered and then start that activity.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF):

> Broadcast Action: Sent when the device goes to sleep and becomes non-interactive.
>
> For historical reasons, the name of this broadcast action refers to the power state of the screen but it is actually sent in response to changes in the overall interactive state of the device.
>
> This broadcast is sent when the device becomes non-interactive which may have nothing to do with the screen turning off. To determine the actual state of the screen, use Display.getState().

You will need to create a receiver class first:

```java
public class SomeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            .
            .
            .
```

And then register it:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val someReceiver = SomeReceiver()

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        val intentFilter = IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        registerReceiver(someReceiver, intentFilter)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(someReceiver)

        super.onDestroy()
    }

}
```

Please bear in mind the new Background Execution Limits and that this most probably will not be what the user wants. Consider instead scheduling a [`JobIntentService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/JobIntentService) to do a burst of work.

### Edit

Due to changes in Android 7 and 8, changes related to Background Execution Limits, apps that target the API level 26 or higher can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest. There are some exceptions thought which you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions)

Comment: as you may know, the BroadcastReceiver  is now deprecated and we can not use it so this solution doesn't work on new devices with android 8+

Comment: Can u send me a github link or a working demo of your soloution ? It is very important for me

Comment: Hi, I finally found the solution but this solution won't work in android 10 it just finds until android 9 do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

### here is my solution but it is not working on android 10 devices

```
if  (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {

       KeyguardManager kgm = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);


       assert kgm != null;
       kgm.requestDismissKeyguard(ScreenLock.this, null);
       setShowWhenLocked(true);
       setTurnScreenOn(true);


   }

   else
   {
       final Window win = getWindow();
       win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
       win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
               | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
               | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);

   }
```